# Search text file for existing data

Tags: python, file, search, text

I have a text file the consists of user names and password. I want to be able to look through this file for existing info before NEW members sign up. In a nutshell, script asks user for username, password, e-mail and email pass. I want to be able to check if the data is pre-existing in the text file (user already a member) before continuing. If the user exists, stop the script. if not, write data to file. I am not bound to any of these methods as I am still learning python.

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
#
#
#       Regitration
#
import os
import sys
import getpass
#import smtplib
from sys import argv

usrnm = argv
usrpw = argv
usreml = argv
usremlpw = argv

prompt = ".:|"

os.system("clear")
print """**********   Registeration   **********

"""

print "Enter your Username"
usrnm = raw_input(prompt)

print "Enter your pasword"
usrpw = getpass.getpass(prompt)

print "Enter your Gmail address"
usreml = raw_input(prompt)

print "Enter your Gmail password"
usrmailpass = getpass.getpass(prompt)

usrname = '%s' % usrnm
usrpassword = '%s' % usrpw
usremail = '%s' % usreml
usremailpass = '%s' % usremlpw

execfile ('usrchck.py')

f = open('tmp.txt', 'w')
f.write('Username. \n')
f.write(usrnm)
f.write("\n")
f.write('User Password. \n')
f.write(usrpw)
f.write("\n")
f.write('User Email Address. \n')
f.write(usreml)
f.write("\n")
f.close()

f = open('tmp.txt', 'r')
ulist = f.read(80)
f = open('usrlist.txt', 'a')
f.write(ulist)
f.write('\n')
f.close()

print ("Closed script")
```

text file info

Username. 
KYD
User Password. 
Password
User Email Address. 
kydice@gmail.com

Username. 
Siff
User Password. 
Password
User Email Address. 
siff@gmail.com

etc....

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Sounds like you know all the steps.  You should work on each one first, then ask specific questions.

Comment: Yay! as if by magic it appeared! So you are looking for help with the theoretical `usrchck.py`, correct? May  we see the format of your existing data, this file you have.

Comment: @ShawnMehan - The beauty of comments :)

Comment: My question is how do i check to see if there is a user with the same name as what's being entered before proceeding.

Comment: @  Shawn Mehan Yes, the file name was put into place for the check but not writen as i don't know how to ....yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def add_user(name,pass,email):
    if not os.path.exists("userlist.txt"):
       with open("userlist.txt","w") as f:
           f.write("")
    entry_text = "%s::%s::%s"%(name,password,email)
    if entry_text in open("userlist.txt").read():
       raise ValueError("User Exists!")
    else:
       with open("userlist.txt","w") as f:
           f.write(entry_text+"\n")
```

Comment: N.B., @Joran Beasley has replaced much of your original code with tight, clean code. This will replace much of what you already have as well as give you the check for existing users. There are other things that could be done with your script, but the journey of a thousand miles begins with the first step!

Comment: @ Joran Beasley Thank you for that tight, clean code. But it was spaced out for learning purposes. (comments and stuff) but i do appreciate the lesson or more so the reminder of how to.

Comment: for learning purposes you should probably not be using `exec`(or `eval` or any of those) ... and all it really replaces is the `f.write`  lines ... all you do is call this function with the appropriate values instead of your `exec` string

Comment: Okay, So i broke the code up into pieces to learn how to link scripts and open files. I am learning this on my own so there is no guide lines or set practice lessons to go by. just to clarify, this is a practice lesson to and from myself. Thank for your input.

Comment: @ Joran Beasley and Shawn Mehan,
Thank you!